# computed column based on ID for receipt no generation

Tags: mysql

I have the below table in SQL: The Receipt No column is computed based on PB + year-month-date with 9 zeroes plus value of first column.

Please help me translate the below query for MYSQL.

```
Create table PBTran
    (
        PBTranID int primary key auto_increment,
        ReceiptNo VARCHAR(30) AS 'PB' + cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + cast(datepart(mm,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(PBTranID AS VARCHAR(10)), 9)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a view:

```
Create table t_PBTran (
    PBTranID int primary key auto_increment
);

Create view v_PBTran as
    select PBTranId,
           concat(date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d), lpad(PBTranId, 8, ' '))
    from t_PBTran;
```

Note:  I don't think this really does what you want.  The computed column in SQL Server puts the *current* date in the receipt.  So, the value changes from one day to the next.  The view does exactly the same thing.

If you actually want the date the id was inserted, you have two options:

1. Have a column with the insertion date in the table and use that instead of the current date/time.
2. Use a trigger to create the receipt.